# Feeds remove item with certainly conditions

Tags: 7, hooks, feeds

Good day

I have a problem with the side of developer

with certainly conditions i need remove a item from source. for example i have in source

nid and phone1 and phone2

but if phone2 is the same that phone1 remove, all this is in updates nodes

```
function custom_feeds_before_update($source, $item, $entity_id){

  $entity = node_load($entity_id);
   if (isset($item['phone 2'])) { 
      if($entity->field_phone_1['und'][0]['value'] == $item['phone 2']){
         unset($item['phone 2']);
      }
  }
}
function custom_feeds_presave($source, $item, $entity_id){

  $entity = node_load($entity_id);
   if (isset($item['phone 2'])) { 
      if($entity->field_phone_1['und'][0]['value'] == $item['phone 2']){
         unset($item['phone 2']);
      }
  }
}
```

something i make wrong? none working never unset if i make dpm in item no appear the item but if i see the node appear update, is other hook

thanks for any help

Comment: Are these two functions actual Drupal hook functions? Documentation shows otherwise. Also is this D7 or D8?

Comment: is for drupal 7

Comment: okay are these two functions actual Drupal hook functions?

Comment: yes hook_feeds_presave and hooks_feeds_before_update

Answer (score 1):

To alter the source items for the D7 version of Feeds, implement the hook `hook_feeds_after_parse()`.

```php
/**
 * Implements hook_feeds_after_parse().
 *
 * Removes duplicate phone numbers for importer 'myimporter'.
 */
function mymodule_feeds_after_parse($source, $result) {
  if ($source->importer->id == 'myimporter') {
    foreach ($result->items as &$item) {
      if (isset($item['phone 1']) && isset($item['phone 2']) && $item['phone 1'] == $item['phone 2']) {
        // If phone 1 and phone 2 are the same, do not import phone 2.
        unset($item['phone 2']);
      }
    }
  }
}
```